# Asus Laptop is constantly freezing, solid red battery light

Tags: freeze, crash, hardware-failure, battery, asus-laptop

Alright so I'm having this problem with my laptop(ASUS ROG G750JM),

It all started when my computer froze and I had to restart it. When I rebooted the computer I was greeted with a "Setup Tool" and having looking at the boot options I noticed that my hard-drive was not being shown in the options.

After some time I was able to get back on Windows but I now get frequent freezes that have been happening more and more in the past two days.

It's gotten to the point where I can no longer use my computer as it completely freezes a few minutes after booting up.

I should add that I ran a Windows memory check to see if it was a problem with the memory and it came back fine. I've also noticed that my battery light is solid red and that my computer shuts off after only a few minutes plugged in even though the battery should be fine for 3 hours(it only charges up to 86%).

Do I need to buy a new battery? Or could it be something else?

Comment: Your computer should operate the same whether it's using the AC power adapter, or running on battery. You can take out the battery if you wish, to see if it runs any different. Based on how it acted after it shutdown/restarted, I'd start troubleshooting with the hard drive. Something sounds like it's corrupt or has failed. I would start by running  SMART test on your HDD.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: I'm trying to use wmic diskdrive get status with command prompt as I can't open Chrome on my computer but it's hanging after I type wmic.

Comment: Alright I got the disk drive status. It says Status OK.

Comment: I also put it through HDTune and it's currently at 1% damaged blocks.